# Simple Way to Access Within JSON NSDictionary Object Values in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, nsdictionary

So I have called a rest API Web Service in Swift and I have my response as an NSDictionary but I am not sure the easiest way to directly access the items within the dictionary. I have included a screen shot. Showing the structure of the response. The elements I would like to access directly are "FirstName" "LastName" and so on.

Any advice on how to do this would be great. I have tried many ways. However not been able to nail it. You can see my last petty attempt. I don't have enough reputation yet to post the photo so included the link. Sorry guys.

Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.
It handles most of the cases that you want to handle.

Comment: I implemented SwiftyJSON and Will never turn back. Thanks @sasquatch for the recommendation.